# How to set Node.js version in Eclipse (Windows OS)

Tags: node.js, angular, eclipse, npm, angular-cli

When trying to run "ng serve" in Eclipse, It returns the following error:

```
You are running version v6.9.4 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.
```

- When running "node -v" in *Eclipse terminal*, it returns: **v6.9.4**
- When running "node -v" in *command prompt*, it returns: **v10.16.3**

How does one upgrade the version of node in Eclipse to use the Angular CLI?

Comment: If you only have need the v10 , you may try to uninstall the older version
or if you need to keep both you can use https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows
and then use 'nvm use <version> [arch]'

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, I don't think that there is an eclipse integrated way to do this process. You simply download node.js + npm from here https://nodejs.org/download/release/ and then open up a terminal or cmd and in your node.js project directory then right "npm install myPackage"